Построение топологии сети без знания информации о коммутаторах?
0
помогите пожалуйста.
Мне нужно построить топологию сканируемой сети. Обязательным условием является отображение коммутаторов на топологии, также нужно узнать MAC-адреса для коммутаторов. Доступа непосредственно к коммутаторам мне не дадут, поэтому нужно узнавать всё с пк. Также известно, что на коммутаторе не настроены протоколы типа SNMP, которые помогли бы узнать данные о коммутаторах. Никакой другой информации о них нет. Известно кол-во коммутаторов - 4. Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне можно использовать в такой ситуации. Может быть, есть какие-то утилиты для этого.
Пробовал через Zenmap построить топологию сети, но она отображает только роутеры.

У коммутаторов вполне может не существовать MAC-адресов вообще

А если есть. Всё равно не понятно, что делать

Ну хотя бы модели коммутаторов известны? Ну или хрен бы с ими, с моделями - хотя бы вендора знаете?

Нет, но что делать, если узнаю?


сканируемой сети  - сканируемой чем?
по тегам к вопросу, я так понял у вас используется оборудование cisco? если есть сетевой доступ к оборудованию (telnet/ssh) построить топологию можно используя информацию cdp/lldp протокола.


Сканировал nmap, доступа к коммутаторам мне не дадут
